# How can I configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that it writes text from where the cursor is, not where it used to be when I started dictating?

Tags: windows, dragon-naturally-speaking

When using Dragon NaturallySpeaking with Microsoft Windows, in some windows Dragon writes the text from where the cursor used to be when I started dictating, instead of writing the text from where the cursor currently is. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.